# Parse or iterate a few records at a time in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I want to pull 5 records at a time into the view (I'm using rails 2.3.8).

I am using will_paginate, and it's working great but:

I want to send those results to the view, 5 records at a time, then add a div, then loop through until they're all shown.

I tried using `find_in_batches`, but I don't know how to access the objects it's returning. Can I use `#{}`?

I know there's `.first` and `.last` methods but is there any such thing as `.second`, `.third`, `.fourth`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an example for `find_in_batches` [in the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_in_batches):

```
Person.find_in_batches(:conditions => "age > 21", :batch_size => 5) do |group|
  sleep(50) # Make sure it doesn't get too crowded in there!
  group.each { |person| person.party_all_night! }
end
```

This may not be the solution you're looking for, though. If you have 5000 records, this will issue 1000 database queries.

A better solution would be using `each_slice`, this method will fetch all records in one database query and split the result set afterwards:

```
Person.find(:all, :conditions => "age > 21").each_slice(5) do |group|
  group.each { |person| person.party_all_night! }
end
```

Comment: You can also use the `Array#in_groups_of` method added by Rails Core Extensions.

Comment: Does it add something else over `each_slice` than the padding option?

Comment: Thanks, Benoit & Swanand for the help. 
Benoit, I really appreciate your answer AND the way you explained it. Great Answer.
I ended up using in_groups_of because I could use it in the view, without sacrificing the will_paginate functionality.

Comment: @BenoitGarret from the [ApiDocs](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of), `in_groups_of` uses `each_slice` in addition to allowing the option to fill the empty items in last group with default values.